# Problema con puntero doble a estructura C

Tags: c

Quiero crear una función a la que le pases un puntero al principio de una lista y añada un nodo al final de ésta. Según tengo entendido esto se hace con punteros dobles, pero no comprendo bien su funcionamiento.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

// Declaración de la estructura
typedef struct nodo{
    char nombre[20];
    struct nodo *sig;
}Nodo;

// Declaración de funciones
Nodo *crearLista();
void anadirNodoFinal(Nodo **lista,char text[20]);

// Funciones
int main(){
    Nodo *lista = crearLista();
    anadirNodoFinal(&lista,"Nodo primero");
    printf("%s",lista->nombre);
    return 0;
}

Nodo *crearLista(){
    Nodo *lista = NULL;
    return lista;
}

void anadirNodoFinal(Nodo **lista, char text[20]){
    Nodo *nuevoNodo = calloc(1,sizeof(Nodo));
    strcpy(nuevoNodo->nombre, text);
    nuevoNodo->sig = NULL;

    if(*lista == NULL){
        lista = &nuevoNodo;
    }else{
        Nodo *aux = *lista;
        while(aux->sig != NULL){
            aux = aux->sig;
        }
        aux->sig = nuevoNodo;
    }
}
```

El programa compila sin problema y se puede ejecutar pero en el printf() de main, después de llamar a anadirNodoFinal() sigue imprimiendo "(null)" por pantalla, cuando quiero que imprima "Nodo primero".

Creo que el problema reside en que **lista apunta a la dirección de *nuevoNodo y este puntero es local a anadirNodoFinal, por tanto al acabar la función se pierde. Sin embargo, si es este el error no sé muy bien como solucionarlo.

Gracias de antemano a todos :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema radica aquí:

```
if(*lista == NULL){
        lista = &nuevoNodo;
}
```

Le estás asignando la dirección de memoria del puntero local al parámetro `lista`, con esto, lo único que logras es que ningún nodo se enlace entre si. Es decir, el puntero `lista`(el de main) siempre apuntará a `NULL`.

Esto es muy peligroso, porqué si estuvieras creando un programa más extenso, se estaría reservando memoria  a cada rato pero como el puntero de inicio (`lista`) apunta a NULL, habrá fuga de memoria.

La solución sería cambiar esta línea:

```
lista = &nuevoNodo;
```

Por esta:

```
*lista = nuevoNodo;
```

**¿Por qué es necesario cambiarlo?**

Esto se debe porqué el objetivo de declarar como parámetro un puntero doble en la función `anadirNodoFinal`, es modificar el contenido del puntero que pasaste como referencia y la única manera de hacerlo, es desreferenciando el puntero `lista`.

Plantearé el funcionamiento de esta sentencia:

```
*lista = nuevoNodo;
```

- Se accede primero al contenido del parámetro `lista`, donde tendrá la dirección de memoria del puntero que pasaste como referencia.
- Después se accede a la dirección de memoria que tenga guardado el parámetro `lista` y se le envía la dirección base (el de primer elemento) del nodo creado (al que apunte `nuevoNodo`).

**Cosas a tomar en cuenta:**

- El nombre que le diste al puntero de inicio no es el 
  correcto, debido a que una lista enlazada no es un 
  nodo, sino una colección de nodos.
  Por ejemplo, le hubiese dado como nombre: `beginNode`. 
  Ahí estarías dando como referencia que el puntero 
  apunta a la dirección base del nodo de inicio (el primero que reservas).
- El parámetro `char text[20]` no necesita llevar un tamaño, debido a que, en realidad es un puntero implícito.

Esto quiere decir, que si yo tengo una función definida de esta forma:

```
void anadirNodoFinal(Nodo **lista, char text[20])
{
  //code
}
```

El compilador interpretará ese código de la siguiente manera:

```
void anadirNodoFinal(Nodo **lista, char* text)
{
  //code
}
```

Si te das cuenta, especificar el tamaño es innecesario, porqué al fin de cuenta, los arrays se pasan por referencia, esto quiere decir, que cada parámetro quien reciba esa dirección base del arreglo, será un puntero.

Hay muchas formas de comprobarlo, por ejemplo:

```
void hello(char name[20])
{
     printf("%d bytes\n", sizeof name);
}
```

Si `name` fuera un arreglo, debería de dar como resultado en pantalla: `20 bytes`; sin embargo, el resultado es `4 bytes` (esto depende de la arquitectura del procesador, si fuera compilado en una máquina de 64 bits, el resultado sería 8 bytes).

Con esto queda claro que el parámetro `name` es un puntero y que no es necesario declararlo como un "array" y mucho menos, agregar un tamaño.

- No necesitamos recorrer toda la lista enlazada para agregar un nodo al final. Puedes declarar otro puntero en el main que se llame `endNode`, este apuntaría a la dirección base del último nodo, con esto te ahorras recorrer con un bucle la lista y es mucho más eficiente.

```
int main()
{
    Nodo *beginNode = crearLista();
    Nodo* endNode = NULL;
    anadirNodoFinal(&beginNode, &endNode,"Nodo primero");
    printf("%s",beginNode->nombre);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
} 

void anadirNodoFinal(Nodo **beginNode, Nodo** endNode, char* text)
{
    Nodo *nuevoNodo = calloc(1, sizeof(Nodo));
    strcpy(nuevoNodo->nombre, text);
    nuevoNodo->sig = NULL;
    (*beginNode == NULL) ? (*beginNode = nuevoNodo) : ((*endNode)->sig = nuevoNodo);
    *endNode = nuevoNodo;
}
```

El código de arriba lo que hace es lo siguiente:

- Si llamamos la función por primera vez, el enlace siguiente del nodo creado apunta a NULL y los punteros `beginNode` y `endNode` quedarán apuntando a la dirección base del nodo de inicio.
- Si llamamos la función por segunda vez, el nodo anterior(en este caso sería el primer nodo) se enlazaría con el nuevo, quedando el puntero `endNode` apuntando al último nodo creado.
- Si llamamos la función por tercera vez, el último nodo (que vendría ser el segundo) se enlazaría con el nuevo nodo (el próximo nodo que será el último de la lista), quedando el puntero `endNode` apuntando al último nodo creado y así sucesivamente se repite el mismo proceso.